# How to add props like fullWidth at particular width like 'sm' in Material UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, responsive

I want to add `fullWidth` prop when the screen size will be `600px` or larger(i.e., `sm`).
I am trying to add the below code, but it's not working.

```
[theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
  fullWidth: true,
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `isWidthDown` or `isWidthUp` methods. Those are available in `@material-ui/core/withWidth`:

```
import withWidth, { isWidthDown } from '@material-ui/core/withWidth';
import SomeComponent from './SomeComponent';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <SomeComponent fullWidth={isWidthDown('sm', this.props.width)} />;
  }
}

export default withWidth()(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks. And for other props like spacing. What I need to write for spacing={20} at the width of sm.

Comment: I guess `spacing={ isSm ? 20 : 0 }` where `isSm = isWidthDown('sm', this.props.width)` should work

Comment: It's not working because sm is for width 600px or larger. So, this statement is going to be true for every width above it. I want it for a specific range of width.

Comment: You mean `md`? If so, then `spacing={ this.props.width === 'md' ? 20 : 0}`. Also, check out this examples: https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/#withwidth-

Comment: I want the spacing to be 0 for a width range 425px-768px. Else the spacing should be 40.

Comment: Well, if you need to be that specific, you could try to declare a variable `const isInRange = (window.innerWidth >= 425 && window.innerWidth <= 768);` and then use it: `spacing={ isInRange ? 0 : 40 }`. But I would suggest to use css media-queries if possible.

Comment: I seems you didn't even notice that `resize`event is debounced. set width of the screen > 960px and reload [sandbox](https://kk7qvlxq55.codesandbox.io/)